# How can I load a script in a JavascriptMVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascriptmvc, stealjs

I know how to load scripts using **steal** however I want to load it before the code in my controller's `init` method is executed. I need the methods from a script file to be defined before the controller initialization.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:** Some background info: I've tried loading the script file using the steal function in the controller like so:

```
steal( 'jquery/controller','jquery/view/ejs', '../js/other.js' )
```

The result was that the file was loaded via `<script>` tag in the head section of the file.
Also jQuery was not defined before loading set file.

Comment: What have you tried and what happened :). It helps to have some background information.

Comment: then() should be doing what you need. You need to show us the complete code that you're trying and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `then()` to define your controller?

```
steal('jquery/controller','../js/other.js').then(function() {
    // other.js is loaded now
    $.Controller(...);
});
```

Comment: Yes I am using then `.then( './views/init.ejs', function($){ ... });`

Comment: Right, I had to use multiple cascading function calls to make it work: `steal().then().then().then()`